# Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed error

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, rocon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im new here. I was trying to install turtlebot by following source installation as suggested in http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Turtlebot%20Installation on rosdistro:kinetic,rosversion: 1.12.12,Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, however with catkin make command execution I got the following error

```
Base path: /home/uma/rocon
Source space: /home/uma/rocon/src
Build space: /home/uma/rocon/build
Devel space: /home/uma/rocon/devel
Install space: /home/uma/rocon/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/uma/rocon/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/uma/rocon/build"
####
/bin/sh: 1: pyrcc5: not found
rocon_qt_gui/rocon_remocon/CMakeFiles/resources_rocon_remocon.dir/build.make:57: recipe for target 'rocon_qt_gui/rocon_remocon/CMakeFiles/resources_rocon_remocon' failed
make[2]: *** [rocon_qt_gui/rocon_remocon/CMakeFiles/resources_rocon_remocon] Error 127
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:693: recipe for target 'rocon_qt_gui/rocon_remocon/CMakeFiles/resources_rocon_remocon.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [rocon_qt_gui/rocon_remocon/CMakeFiles/resources_rocon_remocon.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target _concert_workflow_engine_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_WorkflowsStatus
[  0%] Built target _concert_workflow_engine_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_EnableWorkflows
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

I looked up different forums for this problem, but could not find a proper solution.

Urgent help required.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285406/invoking-%22make--j4--l4%22-failed-error/) by [uma888](https://answers.ros.org/users/34122/uma888/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-03-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-14**:
Please change the title of your question to be a bit more descriptive. Your current title is too generic.

**Comment by [Maarten](https://answers.ros.org/users/34054/maarten/) on 2018-03-14**:
The error is not `Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed` but `/bin/sh: 1: pyrcc5: not found`. Is pyrcc5 installed? (in Ubuntu, you can get it in the `pyqt5-dev-tools` package, not sure whether ROS uses another version).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a similar problem, running `sudo apt install pyqt5-dev-tools` fixed the problem for me.

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2018-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [milkmango](https://answers.ros.org/users/140227/milkmango/) on 2023-02-22**:
Yes, This is the answer for this problem